# Nginx + puma configuration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx

Here's my puma configuration:

```
path = Dir.pwd + "/tmp/puma/"

threads 0,20
environment "production"
daemonize true
drain_on_shutdown true

# _load_from path

bind  "unix://" + path + "socket/puma.sock"
pidfile path + "pid/puma.pid"
state_path path + "pid/puma.state"
```

and here's my nginx configuration:

```
upstream rails_app {
  server /srv/rails/project/tmp/puma/socket/puma.sock;
}

server {
# server_name domain.tld www.domain.tld;
  root /srv/rails/project/public;

  try_files $uri/index.html $uri @rails_app;

  location @rails_app {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_redirect off;

    proxy_pass http://rails_app;
  }

  error_page 500 504 /500.html;
  error_page 502 /502.html;
  error_page 503 /503.html;

  client_max_body_size 4G;
  keepalive_timeout 10;
}
```

And yet, when I restart nginx:

```
sudo service nginx restart
```

I get this:

```
Starting nginx: nginx: [emerg] invalid host in upstream "/srv/rails/project/tmp/puma/socket/puma.sock" in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default:2
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
```

I can get some more clues here:

```
tail -f /var/log/nginx/error.log
2014/04/30 09:07:33 [error] 7517#0: *1 directory index of "/srv/rails/project/" is forbidden, client: <ip address>, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host:  <ip address>
2014/04/30 09:35:55 [emerg] 8245#0: invalid host in upstream "/srv/rails/project/tmp/puma/socket/puma.sock" in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default:2
```

But it doesn't mean much to me I'm afraid!

Also, I'm storing my pid and my sock inside the projects root folder. Is there a dedicated place on an ubuntu server that they should go?

Answer (score 6):

Your configuration is not correct. The right upstream path would be:

`server unix:///srv/rails/project/tmp/puma/socket/puma.sock;`

The unix:// means it's a socket. You could also use tcp://, for example, and point it to a port, like tcp://127.0.0.1:8080